# How to prove the size of the largest sets of Cn is n/2 when n is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Hello everyone this is my first post on this website so if the formatting is off I apologize. I tried my hardest to make sure it was right. Anyway this is my question. I am having a hard time doing this problem on my homework, I know what the terms mean, but I'm having a hard time setting the problem up and where to start with it. So some help would be amazing. I also don't think I fully understand the hint for part B. 
Here is the question: 
An independent set of S of a graph G=(V,E) is any subset of Vertices S subset V whereby no vertices in S are adjacent.

Part A 
List all of the largest independent sets in C2, C4, C5, and C6.

Part B 
Prove that the size of the largest independent sets of Cn is n/2 when n is even

HINT for part B: Find an X subset Y of size n/2 that must be an independent set and explain why. Then show why X U Vk for any vertex Vk not an element of X cannot possibly be an independent set. Thus, X has to be the biggest independent set you can find.

Sorry for such a long question, but I really do need help on this. Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n\ge 4$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be the vertices of the cycle $C_n$ in the cyclic order. Put $X=\{v_1,v_3,\dots, v_{n-1}\}$. It is easy to see that no vertices of $X$ are adjacent, so $X$ is an independent set. Also size of $X$ is $n/2$.

Now  $Z$ be any independent subset of vertices of $C$. Double count a number $N$ of pairs $(v,e)$, where $v\in Z$ and $e$ is an edge incident to $v$. Since each vertex $v$ of $Z$ participates in exactly two such pairs, $N=2|Z|$. On the other hand, since $Z$ is an independent set, any edge $e$ of the graph $C_n$ can participate in at most one such pairs. Since the graph $C_n$ has $n$ edges, we have $N\le n$. Thus $|Z|\le n/2$ and so $X$ is a biggest independent subset of the graph $C_n$.

Comment: thank you so much. Your life saver and I think I understand the concept now. Thank you so much